# What is the efficient way to query the bunch of records?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the hash of field_id and value `{"1379" => 1, "1381" => "test"}` and I want to search for the fields with those field_ids. I was thinking of two solutions :

[image]
 1. loop over the hash and get each field_id to find

[image]

2. map the hash to get the field_id and use where query to search for the field

[image]

I was wonder which one is the best solution since I have many fields in database and I worry about the performance. Could you give me the idea ?

Comment: Post code, not screenshots of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one of course, only one query will be executed when you use `IN` unlike running `find` for individual records.

```
Field.where(id: field_ids)
```

the above query would be executed only once as

```
SELECT * from where fields.id IN (field_ids)
```

But in case of the first one it will be like

```
SELECT * from where fields.id = field_id_1;
SELECT * from where fields.id = field_id_2;
SELECT * from where fields.id = field_id_3;
SELECT * from where fields.id = field_id_4;
...
```

This can prove very costly when the params hash is big.

Hope that helps!